# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN

Tags: java, cosine-similarity

Can you please help me on this one guys.. I am trying to get log of a big decimal (BigDecimal), but I get an exception error message below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN
```

This is what I have:

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(totalDocuments/hitDocuments);
BigDecimal idf = new BigDecimal(Math.log(num.doubleValue()));
BigDecimal termF = new BigDecimal(terms.get(j).getTermFreq());
BigDecimal tfIdf = new BigDecimal(termF.doubleValue() * idf.doubleValue());
terms.get(j).setTfIdf(tfIdf.doubleValue());
```

I get the exception in the second line; How do I get around this? Thank you so much for your kindness. Oh, and by the way I am trying to calculate the "tf-idf" of text files.

Here is the full code

`File[] corpus = new File("files//").listFiles();`
`int totalDocuments = (corpus.length) - 1; //-1 for the suspect document.`

```
    int hitDocuments = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < corpus.length; i++) {
        ArrayList<String> corpusWords = getWords(corpus[i].getAbsolutePath());
        for (int j = 0; j < terms.size(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < corpusWords.size(); k++) {
                if (terms.get(j).getTerm().equals(corpusWords.get(k))) {
                    hitDocuments++;
                }
            }
            //Update the tf-idf
            BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(totalDocuments/hitDocuments);
            BigDecimal idf = new BigDecimal(Math.log(num.doubleValue()));
            BigDecimal termF = new BigDecimal(terms.get(j).getTermFreq());
            BigDecimal tfIdf = new BigDecimal(termF.doubleValue() * idf.doubleValue());
            terms.get(j).setTfIdf(tfIdf.doubleValue());
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `num` is `0` then [Math.log()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) will return `Infinite`

> If the argument is positive **zero** or negative **zero**, then the result is negative **infinity**.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick response, but there is no way num can be zero because the variable `totalDocuments` has a length of `corpusFiles.listFiles.length`. and the variable `hitDocuments` has a value of 1 by default. Thanks again

Comment: I have fixed it with an idea I got from your replies.. I have re-initialiased the variable `hitDocuments = 1;`.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looks like hitDocuments or totalDocuments (or both) is a Double, and that hitDocuments is 0.0.  anything / 0.0 = Double.Infinity (or NaN if totalDocuments is 0.0).  Can't take the log of either.

Comment: This one is the best answer so far for me. Thanks